# MediaSource doesn't contain any method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp, win-universal-app

I followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-playback-with-mediasource and copied following line:

```
mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
```

But Visual Studio shows an error:
"The type name 'CreateFromStoargeFile' does not exist in the type 'MediaSource'"

And `MediaSource` doesn't contain any Method/Property/... The IntelliSense poup doesn't even show.

[image]

[image]

I guess there is something wrong with Visual Studio or the UniversalWindowsPlatform core. I let Visual Studio repair itself but it doesn't work.

**Edit:**
The metadata of MediaSource contains all methods though...
[image]

**Solution:**

I put the `new` keyword in front of the `MediaSource`...

I am ashamed of myself...

Comment: Do you have a reference to the `Windows.Media.Core.dll` assembly?  Do you have `using Windows.Media.Core;` at the top of your class file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshots, it looks like you are using the `new` keyword in front of your method call.

Try removing that.